# Atualizar lista após o push AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

Tenho uma lista com vários dados (`$scope.messages`), porém só alguns dados me interessam. Após o carregamento dessa lista eu faço um `foreach` e pego apenas os dados que me interessam e dou `push` em uma nova lista. Dessa forma:

```
angular.forEach($scope.messages, function(msgBD) {
     if((msgBD.user == $scope.usuario   && msgBD.destino == destino) || (msgBD.user == destino && msgBD.destino == $scope.usuario )){
          $scope.msgs.push(msgBD);
     }
});
     $scope.messages = $scope.msgs;
```

Porém na view o meu `ng-repeat` não atualiza sozinho

```
  <ul class="media-list" ng-repeat="message in messages track by $index">
  {{message.text}}
  </ul>
```

Quando eu utilizo   `$scope.$apply` antes do push funciona perfeitamente:

```
  $scope.$apply(function(){
          $scope.msgs.push(msgBD);
   });
```

Porém da esse erro no console:

> "Error: [$rootScope:inprog]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply

Tem  alguma maneira de resolver esse problema? Ou então tratar esse erro?

---

**UPDATE**
Criei um Fiddle pra exemplificar melhor o meu problema.

1. Abra dois navegadores entre com dois nomes diferentes e faça o Login
2. Clique no usuário que está online(O usuário q você criou no outro
   navegador)
3. Envie uma mensagem
4. Nada acontece, então clique no mesmo usuário pra quem voce enviou
   uma mensagem novamente e verá que a mensagem é atualizada.

**Esse é o problema** a mensagem a lista só "Atualiza" quando clico novamente no usuário que eu enviei a mensagem.

`Fiddle`: http://jsfiddle.net/tjruzpmb/60/

---

**Update 2**

Exemplo do chat funcionando perfeitamente após solução apresentada pelo @oOAkiraOo
http://jsfiddle.net/sinkz/tjruzpmb/103/

OBS: Se muitos usuários estiverem online, é só clicar em limpar usuários.

Comment: O que é essa sua variável "destino"?

Comment: Cara, outra pergunta, em qual evento você está tentando atualizar o seu array? no momento de renderização da tela? em alguma textbox que é alterada?

Comment: No evento que envia a mensagem, to montando um fiddle

Comment: @Techies por acaso você está usando essa exibição dentro de algum `ng-if` ou `ng-show` ? Lembro que certa vez tive problema com isso, a atualização só passava para dentro deles com o $apply(); mas se usado fora do if ou show, ele atualiza em tempo real, sem necessidade de $apply() ou $digest().

Comment: @Techies pelo que entendi, você está tentando criar um chat, é isso?

Comment: `$scope.apply()` faz uso assíncrono de databind, chamando o `$scope.$digest()`, seu uso é recomendado  em poucos casos, geralmente é usado junto com o `$timeout` ou `setTimeout()`. Por esse motivo, o evento quando é chamado mais de uma vez, sem intervalo de tempo, dá esse erro. Ou seja, ele é lento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problema com syncronismo.

Eu resolvi dessa maneira:

```
$scope.novaMensagem = function(message) {
    message.user = $scope.usuarioLogado.login;
    message.destino = $scope.target;
    Message.create(message).then(function(ref) {
        console.log('--> ', ref);
        //$scope.mensagemPara($scope.target); //Não precisa com a inclusão do $watch
    });
    $scope.newmessage.text= "";
    //$scope.newmessage = "";
};
```

**UPDATE 1.0**:
 E para deixar instantaneo, acrescentei o codigo abaixo no controller `chatCtrl`:

```
 Message.all.$watch(function(evnt) { 
        //console.log(evnt);
        var msgs = [];
        $scope.usuario = $scope.usuarioLogado.login;
        angular.forEach(Message.all, function(msgBD) {
            if ((msgBD.user == $scope.usuario && msgBD.destino == $scope.target) || (msgBD.user == $scope.target && msgBD.destino == $scope.usuario)) {
                msgs.push(msgBD);
            }
        });
        $scope.messages = msgs;
    });
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32086/discussion-on-answer-by-ooakiraoo-atualizar-lista-apos-o-push-angularjs)

Answer (score 3):

Opa, tente utilizar `$scope.$digest()` para atualizar suas bindings e seus watchers

Comment: aonde eu coloco ? dentro do foreach?

Comment: Não não, coloca após tudo, após o  $scope.messages = $scope.msgs;. Ele vai atualizar seu bind e mostrar o valor na sua tela. Me avisa se funcionou conforme tua necessidade depois ;)

Comment: Outra coisa, não necessita criar um outro array que seja uma propriedade do teu $scope. Cria um array normal: var msg = [];

Comment: Eu criei um array normal e tentei usar o $digest. Porém deu esse erro:
"Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply

Comment: Coloca num codepen ou num fiddler pra testarmos, por favor?

Comment: Vou tentar fazer

Comment: Aqui está o fiddle: jsfiddle.net/tjruzpmb/60

Comment: Abre dois navegadores, coloca nomes diferentes e clica em login. Depois clica em cima do usuário e envia uma mensagem

Comment: Depois que enviar uma mensagem voce tem que clicar em cima do nome do usuario novamente, só dessa forma a lista é atualizada

Comment: Toda vez q voce fizer um envio de mensagem clique em cima do nome do usuario novamente

Answer (score 2):

Uma opção é utilizar o filtro na lista, ao invés de processá-la e exibi-la modificada.

Similar a [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17946272/3293600), voce pode fazer o seguinte:

```
<ul class="media-list" ng-repeat="message in messages track by $index | filter:{user: usuario, destino: destino}">
  {{message.text}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Da esse erro: "Error: [filter:notarray] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/filter/notarray?p0=0

Comment: vc inicializou os arrays que está usando?? `var messages = [ ]`

Comment: Sim: `$scope.messages= Message.all;`

Comment: O Array é inicializado puxando todos os dados existentes na base

Comment: Esse erro diz: `Expected array but received: 0` é porque a sua variável está com o valor 0 e não um array.... pode ser que está inicializando tarde... (depois do filter ser aplicado)... tenta colocar um $scope.messages = [ ] logo no inicio do module

Comment: Fiz o que tu falou e continua na mesma, não tem nenhuma maneira de fazer no controller?

Answer (score 2):

Teu problema envolve algumas situações.

**Primeiro:**

O atributo message não está sendo iniciado corretamente. Quando você inicia o método Message.all retorna undefined ou indefinido. O correto seria: $scope.message = Message.all || [];

**Segundo:**

Alguns atributos do json tanto de mensagem como de usuários estão com atributos indefinidos. Isso ocorre porque você está usando o ***$scope.usuarioLogado.login*** o correto seria ***$scope.usuarioLogado***, pois você não tem o atributo login definido.O angular não trabalha com valores indefinidos. Tenha cuidado!

**Terceiro:**

Cuidado ao atribuir valores a um array em angular. Ao usar $scope.array = outroArray, você mata a ligação do elemento com o DOM do angular. Ao invés disso use o Arrays.copyOf ***var b = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);***. Dessa forma o angular não perderá seu relacionamento dom o DOM. Esse item gera teu principal problema, a atualização do array não reflete no DOM.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32087/discussion-on-answer-by-emir-marques-atualizar-lista-apos-o-push-angularjs)

Answer (score 2):

O seu problema não pode ser resolvido do modo como você pretende, pois você está envolvendo algumas variáveis que independem da lista de mensagens.

A lista fica armazenada no cliente, ou seja, apenas no computador dele. A partir do momento que ele carregou aquela lista, ele não consegue 'adivinhar' se houve ou não alteração no banco para poder 'recarregar' com os novos dados.

Para que você possa identificar que uma lista de mensagens (ou qualquer outra tabela) sofreu uma alteração no banco, você precisa de um serviço de `socket` que irá fazer justamente o que você precisa:

- Um usuário envia(insere) uma nova mensagem;
- A mensagem é salva no banco de dados;
- O banco de dados envia uma notificação ao serviço de socket (inicializado em todos os clientes);
- O socket notifica todos os usuários logados que houve alteração naquela lista;
- Ai sim é efetuado o carregamento da lista com as novas mensagens;

O serviço de socket vai variar de acordo com o seu backend, mas veja esse site: [socket.io](http://socket.io/) pode te ajudar a procurar pelo que você precisa.

Comment: O Firebase trabalha com Sockets, dessa forma não preciso mexer com essa parte.

Comment: A sim, neste caso, perfeito.